# How can I programmatically add a Controller to an Animator during runtime?

Tags: unity, c#, animation

I am trying to set the Controller of an Animator during runtime using a script.

When I click on the dot in the inspector manually, I can choose one called "Standard Walk", but have not found a way to automate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to swap out controllers at runtime by changing the animator's [`runtimeAnimatorController` property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-runtimeAnimatorController.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works, but how do I set it to one of the existing ones, which I can select when I do it manually?

Comment: By having a reference to it.  From your use of the plural, you would probably want whatever script is doing this to take in an array of `AnimatorController` as a public field, and then you pick which one to assign.  Alternatively, you could use [Resources.LoadAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html) to dynamically load at runtime all the controllers you need.